# setText in a textView on my MainActivity

Tags: java, android, textview

Might be I am going to ask very silly question. Actually I am a .net developer and now switching to **Android Development**.
I have a text view and I want to put text in it using `setText()`.

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

        TextView txView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
        txView.setText("Status Test");
    }
```

and XML code is:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblStatus"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStatusTag"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblImei" />
```

When I run this application it stops automatically.

**Logcat:-**

```
04-29 08:27:02.560 1649-1649/com.example.app 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.app, PID: 1649 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.example.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does an application that "stops automatically" come with a LogCat exception stack trace?

Comment: @TheCapn please check Logcat

Comment: can you put activity_main.xml?

Comment: @SirSC, I have posted **AndroidManifest.xml** please check it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply I have deleted **TextView** component (lblStatus) from **fragment_main.xml** and made some changes at **MainActivity.java**. Code is as below

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       /* if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        } */


        TextView txView = new TextView(this);
        txView.setText("Status Text");
        setContentView(txView);
    }
```

And it is working quite batter.. than other answers because it is very simple :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

1. You should **declare** and **initialize** the TextView in the Fragment
2. Because your Activity instance state must be null cause you didn't save the Activity instance using [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) method.
3. You should add TextView component in fragment_main.xml.

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#e5e5e5"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Declare TextView.
     */
    private TextView myText; 
    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        /**
         * Inititlize.
         */
        myText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Set Value for TextView.
         */
        myText.setText("I'm a TextView");
    }


}

}
```

**Result is**

[image: result]

Comment: I was saving TextView components in Fragment_main.xml from beginning. i just made mentioned changes in MainActivity.java and it workd. Can you please explain it briefly.

Comment: Hi, layout.xml is a user front view as well as an Activity is a screen behaviour. Hence we must integrate the xml and the Activity. So you must call the layout.xml in your corresponding Activity using setContentView() method. Unless you might get null pointer exception, you did not call the corresponding layout in your behaviour of the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

**CODE**

```
     public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    TextView txView;
      @Override

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         txView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
  check();
    }

     public void check()
     {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                      .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                      .commit();

               txView.setText("Status Test");
             }
            else
          {

          txView.setText("Status Test1");
         }
     }
      }
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FFE7DB"  >
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblStatus"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvStatusTag"
            android:layout_below="@id/lblImei" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this. This might do it

Comment: Still Not running I am posting Logcat now

Comment: I jave posted my **Android.Manifest.xml** please check it

Comment: Yes I have just started android programming and this is my second program after "Hello Word"

Comment: you need to work on your xml . u have not used any layout not mentioned xml type

Comment: see how xml should be

Comment: `830      396-460/system_process E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg`

Comment: this error is because your emulator doesnt support sound

Comment: I have posted answer of my question, you can check it

Answer (score 0):

Ravi i think you are using appcompat library and 4.4 api level,so if i am right then you have two layouts file in layout folder one is simple activity xml and other one will be for fragment.xml.

and i think you are declaring this TextView in activity.xml not in Fragment xml file,so at run time you are getting null exception so declare this in Fragment.xml.

Comment: use this in your onCreateView where you are inflating your fragment                                                        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container,false);             
   TextView tv = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
   tv.setText("Hello world");

Comment: I marked as comment to `@Override
        public  void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            myText.setText("New Text");`
and added your given code... and it is Working Fine.

Comment: I have posted an answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I triyed this edit code below and it is working fine for Set textview...
(If you are trying to extends ActionBarActivity than you must import app_compact_v7 and android.support jar properly)
Refresh your project build from project properties in eclipse if there is still showing error...

MainActivity.java    :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {       
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView txView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblStatus);
    txView.setText("Status Test");
}
```

}

activity_main.xml   :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have posted an answer. you can check it.